# Перемена элементов цикла Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Господа, есть такой вот веселенький цикл:

```
if ($blog_type == "masonry" || $blog_type == "masonry-fw") {

            $post_item .= '<div class="masonry-item-wrap">';

            if ($post_format == "quote") {
                $post_item .= '<div class="quote-excerpt heading-font entry-title" itemprop="description">'. $post_excerpt .'</div>';
            } else if ($post_format == "link") {
                $post_item .= '<div class="link-excerpt heading-font entry-title" itemprop="description">'. $post_excerpt .'</div>';    
            } else {
                $post_item .= $item_figure;
            }

            $post_item .= '<div class="details-wrap clearfix">';

            if ($show_title == "yes" && $post_format != "quote" && $post_format != "link") {
                if ($single_author && $remove_dates) {
                    $post_item .= '<h4 itemprop="name headline" class="entry-title no-details"><a href="'.$post_permalink.'">'.$post_title.'</a></h4>';
                } else {
                    $post_item .= '<h4 itemprop="name headline" class="entry-title"><a href="'.$post_permalink.'">'.$post_title.'</a></h4>';
                }   
            }


            if ($show_details == "yes" && $post_format != "quote" && $post_format != "link") {

                if ($single_author && !$remove_dates) {
                    $post_item .= '<div class="blog-item-details">'. sprintf('<span class="date updated">%1$s</span>', $post_date) .'</div>';
                } else if (!$remove_dates) {
                    $post_item .= '<div class="blog-item-details vcard author">'. sprintf(__('By <span itemprop="author" class="fn">%1$s</span> on <span class="date updated">%2$s</span>', 'swiftframework'), $post_author, $post_date) .'</div>';
                } else if (!$single_author) {
                    $post_item .= '<div class="blog-item-details vcard author">'. sprintf(__('By <span itemprop="author" class="fn">%1$s</span>', 'swiftframework'), $post_author) .'</div>';
                }

            }
```

И вот мне необходимо поставить автора под детали и ссылку, то есть взять кусок `if { }` с его содержимым и поставить ниже другого куска if `{ }`, но это каждый раз ведет к тому, что слетает `header` (перестает работать скрипт, отвечающий за то, чтобы при прокрутке страницы у `header` присваивался класс, дающий ему `position:fixed`) и в самом верху образуется черная полоса на всю ширину экрана.

P.S. Причем, если сделать в цикле изменение, сохранить, насладиться видом слетевшего всего, затем убрать изменение (то есть сделать как бы первозданный код), сохранить, то все равно все тлен и ничего не работает, пока не удалишь и не загрузишь конкретно новый документ с кодом на сервер. Вот тоже интересно, почему и зачем так?
Собственно, вопрос
а) может тут вообще ничего менять местами нельзя?
б) может у меня руки просто кривые? я ж не программист, к сожалению. но я брала весь кусок от if до его последней скобки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$post_item .= '<div class="masonry-item-wrap">';
```

и

```
$post_item .= '<div class="details-wrap clearfix">';
```

нужно закрывать в нужных местах

```
 $post_item .= '</div>';
```

Comment: в полном коде есть 48 открывающих div и 47 закрывающих, но разве в этом дело? если я добавлю блок - все слетит, затем отменю добавление и сохраню первоначально исходный код - ничего на место не встанет.

Comment: чудес не бывает и я вам несколько не верю - оно так не работает.  по сути проблемы - скорее всего вы перемещаете `if` с открывающим `<div>`, а закрывыющий стоит неправильно. верстка из-за этого и слетает. я бы вам рекомендовал создать новый файл и добавлять в него логические куски из исходного файла. например вывести просто автора или просто заголовок. постепенно добавляя разные `if`, вы 1) разберетесь как оно работает 2) будете точно знать где что-то пошло не так.

Comment: Кстати, почему закрывающих меньше чем открывающих?

Comment: не знаю. может забыли, может в другом файле подтягивается. это шаблон, там такое не редкость.